# Pickling an enum exposed by Boost.Python

Tags: python, pickle, boost-python

Is it possible to pickle (using cPickle) an enum that has been exposed with Boost.Python? I have successfully pickled other objects using the first method described [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/python/doc/v2/pickle.html), but none of that seems to apply for an enum type, and the objects don't seem to be pickleable by default.

Comment: +1 I can't work out how to do this either, but would very much like to!

(at the moment I convert enums that have to be pickled into integers first)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not as they are in the module. I am given to understand that this is SUPPOSED to be possible, but the way the enum_ statement works prevents this.

You can work around this on the python side. Somewhere (probably in a __init__.py file) do something like this:

```
import yourmodule

def isEnumType(o):
    return isinstance(o, type) and issubclass(o,int) and not (o is int)

def _tuple2enum(enum, value):
    enum = getattr(yourmodule, enum)
    e = enum.values.get(value,None)
    if e is None:
        e = enum(value)
    return e

def _registerEnumPicklers(): 
    from copy_reg import constructor, pickle
    def reduce_enum(e):
        enum = type(e).__name__.split('.')[-1]
        return ( _tuple2enum, ( enum, int(e) ) )
    constructor( _tuple2enum)
    for e in [ e for e in vars(yourmodule).itervalues() if isEnumType(e) ]:
        pickle(e, reduce_enum)

_registerEnumPicklers()
```

This will make everything pickle just fine.

Comment: I just encountered this issue for enums defined inside a class scope, for python 2.7.3.  I manually added: pickle(my_module.my_class.my_enum, reduce_enum), and it worked.  I removed the auto detection of enum types - pickling of top level enums seem to have been fixed.

Comment: That's good to know. Thanks. I haven't worked with BP for several years now, so I am not up on the latest.