# Namespaces mixed up when returning scoped enum from class method

Tags: c++, python, boost-python

I have the following code in C++:

```
class Person
{
    public:
        enum Gender {Male, Female};

        Gender GetGender() const;
}
```

I wrapped it in boost::python in this way:

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(TestPython)
{
    scope the_scope = class_<Person>("Person")
        .def("GetGender", &Person::GetGender);

    enum_<Person::Gender>("Gender")
        .value(Male, Person::Male)
        .value(Female, Person::Female)
        .export_values();
}
```

When I try to call `person.GetGender()` from Python I get the following exception:

```
Can't pickle : attribute lookup **PyBF.TestPython.Gender**.
It guesses the namespace of the Gender (which is actually **PyBF.TestPython.Person.Gender**) enum return type incorrectly.
```

How can I tell the `GetGender` function what type to return explicitly?

Comment: There is some strangeness with the pickleing of enums. see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214969/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we do not have the code that produces the error, I assume it occurs when you try to pickle a Person object.

Your problem is not specifically related to the usage of boost. It lies in cPickle module. It has problem pickling object with nested classes. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677012/python-cant-pickle-type-x-attribute-lookup-failed) for an explanation.  Here's a simple code example that produces the error:

```
import cPickle

class MyOuterClass(object):
    class MyInnerClass(object):
        pass

    def __init__(self):
        self.my_inner_class = self.MyInnerClass()


def pickle_error():
    print "Pickling ..."
    my_outer_class = MyOuterClass()
    print cPickle.dumps(my_outer_class)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pickle_error()
```

Running it produces this output:

```
Pickling ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pickle.py", line 18, in <module>
    pickle_error()
  File "pickle.py", line 15, in pickle_error
    print cPickle.dumps(my_outer_class)
cPickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class '__main__.MyInnerClass'>: 
attribute lookup __main__.MyInnerClass failed
```

As mentioned in the linked answer, when cPickle asks inner class for its name it returns `'__main__.MyInnerClass'`. However, this name can't be found in module's namespace, hence you get the exception.

---

Now you experience this because since there isn't something similar to an enum type in python, boost create an object to represent it. The enum_ construct declares a class in the current scope. By capturing the class scope, you end up creating a nested class within Person and you get the pickle error mentioned above.

There's a couple of solutions to your problem.

The simplest would be to declare the enum outside of Person's scope. You may not want to expose a Person's related enum besides it for code organization. You could then declare the Person class in a sub module so your enum is somewhat declared close to your class without being too public.

You could also take a look at [boost's pickle support](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/python/doc/v2/pickle.html). However I haven't tried it.

A third solution could be to use something else than pickle to store your object.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible you have another Male, Female defined somewhere? otherwise I don't see how this compiles.
Try Adding the class scope:

```
enum_<Person::Gender>("Gender")
    .EXPORT_ENUM_VALUE(Person::Male)
    .EXPORT_ENUM_VALUE(Person::Female)
    .export_values();
```

Comment: Sorry I updated the post, I didnt entirely copy my code, hope it makes more sense now